# Why SetWindowPos does not change ComboBoxEx dropdown height?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, combobox, controls

I'm testing ComboBoxEx control with images. I've used microsoft [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) without any big changes. It works, but comboboxex dropdown does not show the list! In fact, SetWindowPos function does not change ComboBoxEx dropdown height anyway!
I'm using VS2010sp1, released, win32 and Common Control 6.0 pragma in window7sp1x64. The only way to show dropdown list completely is change ComboboxEx height in CreateWindowEx to a big value!
How can I change ComboBoxEx dropdown list programmatically be worked?

I want to create a combo box, show text and image together. I've used following code exactly:

```
HWND *CreateComboBoxEX(HWND hwndParent)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_USEREX_CLASSES;

    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_COMBOBOXEX, L"", 
    WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 0, 0, 200, 40,
    hwndParent, (HMENU)NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
        return(NULL);
    return(hwnd);
}

BOOL WINAPI AddItems(HWND hwndCB)
{

//  Declare and init locals.
COMBOBOXEXITEM cbei;
int iCnt;


typedef struct {
    int iImage;
    int iSelectedImage;
    int iIndent;
    LPTSTR pszText;
} ITEMINFO, *PITEMINFO;

ITEMINFO IInf[ ] = {
    { 0, 3,  0, L"first"}, 
    { 1, 4,  1, L"second"},
    { 2, 5,  2, L"third"},
    { 0, 3,  0, L"fourth"},
    { 1, 4,  1, L"fifth"},
    { 2, 5,  2, L"sixth"},
    { 0, 3,  0, L"seventh"},
    { 1, 4,  1, L"eighth"},
    { 2, 5,  2, L"ninth"},
    { 0, 3,  0, L"tenth"},
    { 1, 4,  1, L"eleventh"},
    { 2, 5,  2, L"twelfth"},
    { 0, 3,  0, L"thirteenth"},
    { 1, 4,  1, L"fourteenth"},
    { 2, 5,  2, L"fifteenth"}
};

// Set the mask common to all items.
cbei.mask = CBEIF_TEXT | CBEIF_INDENT |
            CBEIF_IMAGE| CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;

for(iCnt=0;iCnt<MAX_ITEMS;iCnt++){
    // Initialize the COMBOBOXEXITEM struct.
    cbei.iItem          = iCnt;
    cbei.pszText        = IInf[iCnt].pszText;
    cbei.cchTextMax     = sizeof(IInf[iCnt].pszText);
    cbei.iImage         = IInf[iCnt].iImage;
    cbei.iSelectedImage = IInf[iCnt].iSelectedImage;
    cbei.iIndent        = IInf[iCnt].iIndent;


    // Tell the ComboBoxEx to add the item. Return FALSE if 
    // this fails.
    if(SendMessage(hwndCB,CBEM_INSERTITEM,0,(LPARAM)&cbei) == -1)
        return FALSE;
}
// Assign the existing image list to the ComboBoxEx control 
// and return TRUE. 
// g_himl is the handle to the existing image list
SendMessage(hwndCB,CBEM_SETIMAGELIST,0,(LPARAM)g_himl);

// Set size of control to make sure it's displayed correctly now
// that the image list is set.
SetWindowPos(hwndCB,NULL,20,20,250,120,SWP_NOACTIVATE);

return TRUE; 
}
```

In WM_CREATE section of WindowProc:

```
himglist = ImageList_Create(24, 24, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 0, 0);
hBitmap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_IMGLIST));
ImageList_Add(himglist, hBitmap, 0);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
hwndComboBoxEx = CreateComboBox(hWnd);
AddItems(hwndComboBoxEx);
```

The program show combobox with text and image, bot when I click on it, it does not show the dropdown list. I want to see the dropdown list completely.
I've checked SetWindowPos. It change ComboBoxEx Width, but not Height!
I'm confused! What's wrong with it?

Comment: Not totally understanding the question.

Comment: Please post some code to illustrate what you are trying to do and what isn't working for you.

Comment: [How to Create a Simple Combo Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298364.aspx) contains sample code. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to guess, where you went wrong. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you calling `DefWindowProc` for window messages that you're not explicitly handling?  Do you swallow the message that's supposed to be opening the dropdown? The 'c' part of 'mcve' means something that can be run as is that demonstrates the problem. Also: `CreateComboBoxEX` isn't returning a `HWND` its returning a `*HWND`. In this case it _probably_ doesn't matter, but you should be careful about types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComboBoxEx has a child window which is a regular ComboBox, some messages don't get passed properly. I think it also depends on Window version.

You should set the height when you create the control. Also remove the pointer.

```
HWND CreateComboBoxEX(HWND hwndParent)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_USEREX_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    //*** put the correct height in here: *** 
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_COMBOBOXEX, L"", 
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 0, 0, 200, 120, 
            hwndParent, (HMENU)NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);

    return(hwnd);
}
```

You can later use `SetWindowPos` to change X/Y position and width.

Another method:

Use `SetWindowPos` to change X/Y position and Width of ComboBoxEx. Then resize the child of ComboBoxEx to set the correct height.

```
//height will have no effect here
SetWindowPos(hwndCB, NULL, 20, 20, 250, 120, SWP_NOACTIVATE);

HWND child = (HWND)SendMessage(hwndCB, CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL, 0, 0);
if (child)
{
    //Resize using the same width, but different height. And don't move. 
    SetWindowPos(child, NULL, 0, 0, 250, 120, SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```